# Non uniform Multidimensional arrays in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl

Is it possible to define multidimensional arrays in Perl which can have non uniform dimension? Like the following example?

```
Agenda = @( 'Monday' , {'Tuesday',Lunch} , 'Wednesday' , 'Thursday', {'Friday','Lunch','Dinner'})
```

Notice how how the second element `{'Tuesday',Lunch}` is an array itself.

Comment: Yes you can use an array of array references. Each array reference can have its own dimension. See [perldoc perldsc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) for more information

Comment: Technically there's no "multidimensional array" like in statically typed languages. You can define an array and put another array (references) inside, so yes. Your syntax is not valid Perl though. It should be something like: @Agenda = ('Monday', ['Tuesday','Lunch'], ...);

Comment: @PerlAncar `{'Tuesday',...}` is valid perl - it is as hash ref rather than an array ref though

Comment: @ChrisTurner Yes, should've said "is not the correct Perl syntax for creating array refs"

Comment: Further reading: https://p3rl.org/REF

Comment: @ChrisTurner, but `... {'Friday','Lunch','Dinner'} ...` is going to be a problem under `strict` complaining: "Odd number of elements in anonymous hash"

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is, just use array references. Using JSON as output format to illustrate your example:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON;

my @agenda = (
    'Monday',
    ['Tuesday', 'Lunch'],
    'Wednesday',
    'Thursday',
    ['Friday', 'Lunch', 'Dinner'],
);

print JSON->new->pretty->encode(\@agenda);
```

Output:

```json
$ perl dummy.pl
[
   "Monday",
   [
      "Tuesday",
      "Lunch"
   ],
   "Wednesday",
   "Thursday",
   [
      "Friday",
      "Lunch",
      "Dinner"
   ]
]
```

**EDIT** I personally would use a list of hash refs instead, i.e.

```perl
my @agenda = (
   {
       day    => 'Monday',
       events => [],
   },
   ...
   {
       day    => 'Friday',
       events => ['Lunch', 'Dinner'],
   },
   ...
);

foreach my $entry (@agenda) {
   my $day    = $entry->{day};
   my $events = $entry->{events};

   print $day . ": " . join(" ", @{ $events }) . "\n";
}
```

or even use a hash ref for `events`.